# Unity 3D Object Constantly Cloning

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

This is unity 2d angry bird style game example. I working on resetter codes. Resetter code below (I changed some parts). I using ball on this project instead of birds. So, I want to if ball is stoped after to throw load new ball to catapult. But It doesn't work correctly. First of all. I wrote if ball count == 0 clone the object. But its alwaws clonning when ball was stoped. On the other hand I cant use cloned object for throwing. Cloned object not on the catapult. Sorry for my bad english but this problem my last
 phase on this game.

for example 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3gwinw8chyeh59/error.png?dl=0

This is game tutorial link.
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/making-angry-birds-style-game

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Resetter : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody2D projectile;          //  The rigidbody of the projectile
public float resetSpeed = 0.025f;       //  The angular velocity threshold of the projectile, below which our game will reset

private float resetSpeedSqr;            //  The square value of Reset Speed, for efficient calculation
private SpringJoint2D spring;           //  The SpringJoint2D component which is destroyed when the projectile is launched

public int BallCount;              // I using this value for  I need new ball or not
public Rigidbody2D  projectileSD; // Ball 





void Start ()
{
    BallCount = 1;

    //  Calculate the Resset Speed Squared from the Reset Speed
    resetSpeedSqr = resetSpeed * resetSpeed;

    //  Get the SpringJoint2D component through our reference to the GameObject's Rigidbody
    spring = projectile.GetComponent <SpringJoint2D>();
}

void Update () {


    //  If the spring had been destroyed (indicating we have launched the projectile) and our projectile's velocity is below the threshold...
    if (spring == null && projectile.velocity.sqrMagnitude < resetSpeedSqr) {
        //  ... call the Reset() function
    //  Reset ();



        if (BallCount == 0 ); 
        {
            ObjeyiKlonla();


        }



    }
}

void ObjeyiKlonla() {              // Clone object






                    Rigidbody2D clone;
                    clone = Instantiate (projectileSD, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
                    clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward * 1);
        BallCount ++;



}

void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D other) {
    //  If the projectile leaves the Collider2D boundary...
    if (other.rigidbody2D == projectile) {
        //  ... call the Reset() function
        //Reset ();
    }
}

void Reset () {
    //  The reset function will Reset the game by reloading the same level
    //Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    BallCount =0;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to fix your Logic error first. You said that you're destroying the spring component After you use it. But the Script is still trying to access it after you have used the catapult or even when you start using the catapult. Either Reference your spring component properly or Turn of the function that the script is trying to use the Spring component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
void Update(){

  if(projectile.GetComponent <SpringJoint2D>() && projectile.velocity.sqrMagnitude < resetSpeedSqr)
        {
                if (BallCount <= 0 ); 
                  {
                          ObjeyiKlonla();


                  }
        }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I will try this immediately.